# how to use random access to streams properly?

Tags: c++

consider the following code :

```
int main()
{
    fstream xyz("file.txt",fstream::ate|fstream::in|fstream::out);
    xyz.seekp(0,fstream::beg);
    xyz << "this is ";
    xyz.close();
}
```

file.txt contains: `"a c++ program"`

I want the output to be `"this is a c++ program"` but the output is `"this is ogram"`.
How can I rewrite the code to get the desired output?

Comment: You are writting a string from the begining of the file. Thus rewritting the existing content. You need to read the first line to append what you need.

Comment: as he said. there's no built-in functionality to prepend text.

Comment: 'Random access to stream' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the first characters by typing `this is`.

Use `std::getline()` and store the line in a string and then type this is and add the string you stored the line in.

Comment: Ok. So I tried to do that but it didn't work . this is the code :
int main()
{
fstream xyz("file.txt",fstream::ate|fstream::in|fstream::out);
xyz.seekg(0,fstream::beg);
string h = "this is ";string x;
getline(xyz,x);
h.append(x);
xyz.seekp(0,fstream::beg);
xyz << h ;
cout << h;
xyz.close();
}